# Google is no longer honoring exact search phrases

Tags: google-search

I have relied on exact search term (" ") compliance with Google for years. It is no longer working.

The search "solubility of hydrogenated vegetable oil in DMSO" returns 27,800 results, none of which apparently contain the search phrase. The " " is being ignored. **So**, the search results have **absolutely nothing to do** with the **SPECIFIC FACT** that I am looking for. (And **if it worked as before**, i.e. said "no matches found, trying the search without quotes" I would try other options such as writing out "dimethyl sulfoxide.")

Suggestions?

Comment: I cleared my cache and cookies and changed to a different VPN server, and now I am seeing what you are.  Zero results.  Bizarre.

Comment: [Full comments transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/150456)